# How do I delete all the files with .bak extension in a particular folder and its subfolders C:\User Manual\ using the command prompt?

Tags: command, command-prompt

How do I delete all the files with .bak extension in a particular folder and its subfolders C:\User Manual\ using the command prompt?

I tried del \s \q "C:\User Manual*.bak" but it throws up an error

"Could Not Find C:\s"

Could someone please help me with this and make me understand what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems what you want to do is:

```
del /s /q "C:\User Manual*.bak"
```

`/s` is for subdirectories and `/q` is for the quiet mode.

Notice it's slash a symbol ( `/` ) instead of a backslash ( `\` ).

When it gets a backlash the command expects it to be the names of the files to delete and that's why it warns that it couldn't find c:\s (because you were already on the c: unit while executing the command).

You can find the syntax of the `del` command here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/del

Comment: thank you so much, what worked was del /s /q "C:/User Manual/*.bak", it was the slash